# Seeking examples of scripts/syntax for testing MongoDB with YCSB

Tags: mongodb, centos, ycsb

I'm testing the performance of MongoDB on a single system using YCSB. I'd like to get a sense of the performance using SSDs compared to spinning disks.

I have CentOS, MongoDB, and YCSB installed. I have stumbled around a bit with basic examples, but have yet to see a step by step of starting from this setup to loading to running to reviewing. I keep seeing bits and pieces, but not enough to get me up and running.

If anyone could please provide a command line for these steps, it would be most appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide on how to run Yahoo! Cloud System Benchmark (YCSB) using Mongodb.

- https://github.com/samanca/YCSB/tree/master/mongodb
- https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki

Working example using Python and Java to test Mongodb:

- https://github.com/richcar58/MongoDBTools/blob/master/RunYcsb/runycsb/fabfile.py